# How to remove a time period from another time period?

Tags: algorithm

I wanna remove just a time period without a date, from another time period.
for example, assume, I have a time period like `08:00 to 16:00`, and I wanna remove `10:00 to 12:00` period from that period time.
actually, the first period of time has been converted to two periods of time. `08:00 to 10:00` and `12:00 to 16:00`.
What is the best way to implement it? it should be implemented just with  `if else`? or it has another best way to implement it.

Comment: Answer  depends on usage. If you are going to deal with many time periods, you'd better to make appropriate data structure (some kind of segment tree perhaps). For single period with the only removed interval - if-logic is suitable.